# The command '/bin/sh -c npm install --silent' returned a non-zero code: 254

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, npm-install

When m trying to craete image of react app  with docker[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaHCC.png)file its saying...

```
    The command '/bin/sh -c npm install --silent' returned a non-zero code: 254
```

Here is my dockerfile

```
# Pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: remove the `--silent` flag so you can see what error npm gives you, then fix it.

Comment: I am facing similar issue, have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that npm is reading `package.json` from the place you're copying it to.

Answer (score 0):

This basically happens when something is broken while docker tries to install JS packages. As the error code "254" stands for all types of installation failures, the only way to get the specific issue is by running the "*install*" or "*ci*" command without *--silent*.